# Figure out how to use Roles in a CMS system for C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hey,
I am building a content management system and so far I am trying to get a member's area to work.  I figured out the CreateUserWizard and the Login controls.  I also used `Roles.AddUserToRole(RegisterUser.UserName, "Member");` upon account creation to assign the user the role of a "Member".  I have been googling but I havent been able to find a solid way on how to restrict either a directory or a page to make it so that only "Member" users can access it, otherwise redirect to login page.  Can anyone give me an idea for this?  Also I had a related question, when I go on to the site and I am NOT logged in, what is my default role? is it guest or just null?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-logged-in users have no roles.

You can restrict specific areas of your site in Web.config.

First, disallow access to the entire site:

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
    <deny users="*" roles="" />
</authorization>
```

You can then selectively grant access to specific areas using the `<location>` element:

```
<location path="Login.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="SomeFolder/">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Member" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

- `users="?"` means anonymous (non-logged-in) users
- `users="*"` means all logged-in users.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the default role to the page or directory by checking the Authorization of the user on the page load event.

Moreover the default user will be the guest.